# Open Liberty NullPointerException while deploying the EAR file

Tags: open-liberty

**Exception**

While deploying the `.ear` file on open-liberty. Getting the `NullPointerException`. Can you please let me know whats is missing to fix this problem? Any hint.

**Logs:**

```
[INFO] [ERROR   ] CWWKZ0106E: Could not start web application.
[INFO] [ERROR   ] CWWKZ0004E: An exception occurred while starting the application xxx-app-name. The exception message was: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

**Stack Trace:**

More details on which class throwing the `NullPointerException`.

```
------Start of DE processing------ = [5/5/21, 20:01:18:834 BST]
Exception = java.lang.NullPointerException
Source = com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.SimpleDeployedAppInfoBase
probeid = 535
Stack Dump = java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxws.utils.JaxWsUtils.getServiceName(JaxWsUtils.java:133)
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxws.metadata.builder.AnnotationEndpointInfoConfigurator.config(AnnotationEndpointInfoConfigurator.java:82)
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxws.metadata.builder.EndpointInfoBuilder.invokeConfigurators(EndpointInfoBuilder.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxws.metadata.builder.EndpointInfoBuilder.build(EndpointInfoBuilder.java:95)
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxws.ejb.EJBJaxWsModuleInfoBuilderHelper.buildEjbWebServiceEndpointInfos(EJBJaxWsModuleInfoBuilderHelper.java:55)
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxws.ejb.EJBJaxWsModuleInfoBuilder.build(EJBJaxWsModuleInfoBuilder.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxws.support.JaxWsModuleMetaDataListener.extendModuleMetaData(JaxWsModuleMetaDataListener.java:100)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.SimpleDeployedAppInfoBase$ModuleContainerInfoBase.createModuleMetaData(SimpleDeployedAppInfoBase.java:198)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.SimpleDeployedAppInfoBase.preDeployApp(SimpleDeployedAppInfoBase.java:532)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.SimpleDeployedAppInfoBase.installApp(SimpleDeployedAppInfoBase.java:508)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.module.internal.DeployedAppInfoBase.deployApp(DeployedAppInfoBase.java:349)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.ear.internal.EARApplicationHandlerImpl.install(EARApplicationHandlerImpl.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.StartAction.execute(StartAction.java:149)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.ApplicationStateMachineImpl.enterState(ApplicationStateMachineImpl.java:1352)
    at com.ibm.ws.app.manager.internal.statemachine.ApplicationStateMachineImpl.run(ApplicationStateMachineImpl.java:897)
    at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.ExecutorServiceImpl$RunnableWrapper.run(ExecutorServiceImpl.java:238)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Does your `@WebService` or `@WebServiceProvider` annotated Web Service have a value for the `serviceName` property? If so is there a non-empty value set in it?

Comment: @ThomasJohnson - Thanks for your reply. Since I'm converting the IBM WAS traditional project into open Liberty. So the project uses EJB 2.0 configurations with `ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xmi`enterprise beans defined. I also knew it's service name missing - is it `server.xml` - if it's not EJB 3.0 annotations?

Comment: since your migrating from traditional WebSphere and you mentioned EJB 2.0, some clarification will help me get you the right info. Is there an EJB based Web Service in this project? If so, do you know if it was JAX-RPC originally that you're migrating it to JAX-WS, or was it always JAX-WS? If it is a JAX-WS EJB endpoint then, you'll see a `@WebService` annotation on the EJB Web Service Implementation, is that present?

Comment: @ThomasJohnson - Yes there is EJB based Web-service in the project. It's JAX-RPC originally based on EJB configuration with `ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml`. The project do not uses annotations which means no `@Webservice`annotation present. The soap services are implemented using JAX-RPC method.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the info! Well then, I can tell you that JAX-RPC isn't supported in Open Liberty, so if your app contains a JAX-RPC Web Service it won't be deployable unless you migrate it to JAX-WS.

Comment: @ThomasJohnson - Thanks for rectifying before jump in mud further. EJB3.0 with JAX-WS is also having some issues with open liberty. Please see my this post for sample project - https://github.com/WASdev/sample.ejb/issues/20

Comment: @ThomasJohnson - I confirmed JAX-WS working fine. The above example of open Liberty earlier versions was having some license issue. Updated the version number and license problem went away.

Comment: OK, so the original NullPointerException issue is no longer occuring, but you are still hitting the issue mentioned in the github issue you opened above? I ask in order to make sure I get you an update on the WASDev issue if that's still needed?